# How to make the roll button the default allowing enter press?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I wrote a program to randomly select an image and display it in the window every time a button is pressed. Mow I am trying to figure out how to make the "Roll Dice" button the default allowing enter press.

Driver:

```
public class MCobbM10A1 {

    static int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
    static int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static WidgetPanel widget;
    static GraphicPanel myPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Dice Roller");
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        myPanel = new GraphicPanel();
        myPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 200);
        myFrame.add(myPanel);
        JPanel lastPanel = new JPanel();
        myFrame.add(lastPanel);
        widget = new WidgetPanel();
        widget.setBounds(0, 250, 500, 300);
        myFrame.add(widget);
        widget.rollButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent newRoll) -> {
            new MCobbM10A1().myNewRollButtonPressed();
        });
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
    }
    private void myNewRollButtonPressed() {
        myPanel.newRoll();
    }
}
```

And here is the WidgetPanel:

```
public class WidgetPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton rollButton;
        WidgetPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            rollButton = new JButton();
            rollButton.setBounds(350, 200, 100, 25);
            rollButton.setText("Roll Dice");
            this.add(rollButton);
            JLabel fixBug = new JLabel();
            this.add(fixBug);
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make the "Roll Dice" button the default allowing enter press.

You assign the default button to the JRootPane of your frame.

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(…);
```

One way to do this is:

```
@Override
public void addNotify()
{
    super.addNotify();

    JFrame frame = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( rollButton );
    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(rollButton);
}
```

The `addNotify()` method is invoked when a panel is added to the frame.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your question but why are you creating a new object for each roll?

```
        widget.rollButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent newRoll) -> {
            new MCobbM10A1().myNewRollButtonPressed(); // <--- new MCobbM10A1 object
        });
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
    }
    private void myNewRollButtonPressed() {
        myPanel.newRoll();
    }
```

Why not just do this?

```
    widget.rollButton.addActionListener((ae) ->
            myPanel.newRoll());
```

Comment: I was just using the same method my professor showed us several weeks ago on a different program. This way seems a whole lot simpler. Thank you!